# Get property with lowest value from ArrayList of objects

Tags: java

I have ArrayList containing objects inside of it, every object in the ArrayList has a property and I wan't to see which of these objects has the lowest value on that property. Here's my code + Object structure

```
class ServerInfo{

   public int playerCount = 0; //This is different per every object in the array list
}

List<ServerInfo> onlineServers = new ArrayList<ServerInfo> //From this array i want object with lowest 'playerCount' property value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
ServerInfo elemWithMin = onlineServers.get(0);
int min = onlineServers.get(0).playerCount;
for(int i = 1; i < onlineServers.size(); i++) {
    if(onlineServers.get(i).playerCount < min) {
        min = onlineServers.get(i).playerCount;
        elemWithMin=onlineServers.get(i);
    }
}
```

At the end of this loop, `elemWithMin` will have the element with the minimum value of `playerCount`.

**A quick test:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ServerInfo> onlineServers = new ArrayList<ServerInfo>();
        ServerInfo si1 = new ServerInfo();
        ServerInfo si2 = new ServerInfo();
        ServerInfo si3 = new ServerInfo();
        si1.playerCount = 20;
        si2.playerCount = 10;
        si3.playerCount = 30;
        onlineServers.add(si1);
        onlineServers.add(si2);
        onlineServers.add(si3);
        ServerInfo elemWithMin = onlineServers.get(0);
        int min = onlineServers.get(0).playerCount;
        for (int i = 1; i < onlineServers.size(); i++) {
            if (onlineServers.get(i).playerCount < min) {
                min = onlineServers.get(i).playerCount;
                elemWithMin = onlineServers.get(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The minimum value of payerCount: " + elemWithMin.playerCount);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The minimum value of payerCount: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 stream like below :

```
ServerInfo serverInfoWithMinPlayerCount = onlineServers.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(ServerInfo::getPlayerCount)).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

Comment: What is there is no minimum?

Comment: You can instead use `.orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new)`

Comment: That what I was suggesting - to modify your (great) answer.

Comment: I don't have function getPlayerCount , only the property.

Comment: In Object Oriented Programming, there is a concept of Encapsulation, where you would have a private attribute and a getter/setter to access it. So you can create a getter to access your private attribute.

Comment: I don't have access to the API eg. ServerInfo.php